# How to make dir command in windows output like ls command on linux?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

`dir` is the command in windows to list what files are there in the current position, like the `ls` command in linux. However, their default information to display is different. Here is one of the example output of windows `dir`:

```
2016-06-30  03:47 PM    <DIR>          .
2016-06-30  03:47 PM    <DIR>          ..
2015-06-04  03:49 PM            12,292 .DS_Store
2016-06-10  05:10 PM                11 .gitattributes
2016-06-30  03:47 PM               318 .gitignore
2015-09-25  10:09 AM                 0 .gitmodules
2016-08-03  11:25 AM    <DIR>          app
2015-08-10  05:07 PM             2,502 artisan
2016-06-30  03:47 PM    <DIR>          bootstrap
2016-06-30  03:47 PM             1,361 composer.json
2016-03-17  06:00 PM            82,167 composer.lock
2015-08-10  05:07 PM               147 CONTRIBUTING.md
2016-06-30  03:47 PM             1,310 error.log
2015-08-10  05:07 PM               583 phpunit.xml
2016-09-05  05:37 PM    <DIR>          public
2015-08-10  05:07 PM             1,816 readme.md
2016-06-30  03:47 PM        13,993,746 requests.log
2015-08-10  05:07 PM               538 server.php
2016-06-30  04:55 PM    <DIR>          vendor
              13 File(s)     14,096,791 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  778,356,928,512 bytes free
```

It does the job, but it uses one line for one file and is showing information that I don't need. Usually I just want a quick reminder on what is inside the folder and are not interested in when file was changed. In linux, the output for `ls` will be like

```
app         artisan bootstrap  composer.json compser.lock CONTRIBUTING.md error.log 
phpunit.xml public  readme.xml public        readme.md    requests.log    server.php 
vendor
```

It is much more compact and takes fewer lines. For me, it is easier to read and as it takes less lines, the previous command are kept in the screen too. Window's `dir` command is like keep using `ls -l` in linux.

So, the question, is there a way to change the default settings of `dir` command in windows to make it behaves like `ls` in linux? Or if it is not possible to make it default, at least an option to be type every time?

Comment: Get cygwin and put it's bin on your ```PATH``` then you can just use ```ls```

Comment: Well, this solves the problem, but don't you think it is a bit overkill? I don't use command line that much, just a few minutes a day for some works that must be done in command line. That will be my final choice if there are not other options.

Comment: Ah, @cytsunny yeah it doesn't make sense for you. I did that a while ago when I was still trying to make windows work for me. I've since given up on windows and have moved to linux. It made sense for me to do it since I spent 1/2 my day in the command line.

Comment: To me, if you are using command line that much, dual-boot with linux, using a VM with linux or simply switch to linux is a better option then using cygwin. When I am using Ubuntu at home (I use windows at work only), I feel that their support on command line is much better that one would find that doing some job, especially those related to system settings, on command line is better. In Windows, I would really just stick to GUI.

Comment: [Bring the *nix "ls" to Windows with GNU ls](http://lifehacker.com/298887/bring-the-nix-ls-to-windows-with-gnu-ls)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some detail reading on the documentation on `dir` command, the answer is `dir /W` or `dir /D`. The only difference is just the way they order files. `dir /D` is column first and `dir /W` is row first.

Reference: http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm

Comment: On Windows running a command or console application with parameter `/?` results in getting output the help for the command / console application like on Linux running an console application with `-h` or `--help`. Try it out with `dir /?` executed in a command prompt window. You can read about the bare format get with `/B` most often used on using command __DIR__ in a batch script as it lists the found files/folders just with name without path or in case of `/S` also used with path.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I would prefer /D instead because /B still has the problem of having one file takes up entire line. Also, I think having square bracket on folder in wide mode is also helpful to distinguish between file and folder.

Answer (score 6):

Uses bare format (no heading information or summary, only the information itself).

type `dir /b` on your command prompt. its like `ls` on terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can also combine options such as `dir /D/O:GN` (in this case, lists the files by columns, directories first enclosed in brackets, than regular files ordered by name).